# HHTTPService Error

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to debug an issue by going to the most basic of tasks.

I have an app written in adobe flex (action script 3) that I want to have interact with a web service.  Because it appears I can't access the server, I've created a simple app.

Source code for the ActionScript

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">
    <mx:HTTPService id="concat" url="concat.php" resultFormat="text" method="POST">
        <mx:request xmlns="">
            <stringOne>{stringOne.text}</stringOne>
            <stringTwo>{stringTwo.text}</stringTwo>
        </mx:request>
    </mx:HTTPService>

    <mx:VBox top="10" left="10">
        <mx:HBox verticalAlign="middle">
            <mx:Label text="String 1:"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="stringOne"/>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox verticalAlign="middle">
            <mx:Label text="String 2:"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="stringTwo"/>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HRule width="100%"/>
        <mx:Button label="Concatenate!" click="concat.send()"/>
        <mx:Text fontSize="14" text="{concat.lastResult}"/>
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Code for the PHP

```
<?php

$stringOne = $_POST['stringOne'];
$stringTwo = $_POST['stringTwo'];

print $stringOne . $stringTwo;

?>
```

When I fill in the fields and press the button nothing happens.  Ideas?  Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but normally when you try to access an HTTPService you would do so with URL Variables.  That said your code looks solid and modeled after the Flex examples http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html .  Be sure to test your PHP Script outside of Flex.  Also use a tool, like ServiceCapture or the Flash Builder Network Monitor to view the request you're sending to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one and let us know:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">
    <mx:HTTPService id="concat" url="concat.php" resultFormat="text" method="POST" fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)" result="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.result.toString())">
        <mx:request xmlns="">
            <stringOne>{stringOne.text}</stringOne>
            <stringTwo>{stringTwo.text}</stringTwo>
        </mx:request>
    </mx:HTTPService>

    <mx:VBox top="10" left="10">
        <mx:HBox verticalAlign="middle">
            <mx:Label text="String 1:"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="stringOne"/>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox verticalAlign="middle">
            <mx:Label text="String 2:"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="stringTwo"/>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HRule width="100%"/>
        <mx:Button label="Concatenate!" click="concat.send()"/>
        <mx:Text fontSize="14" text="{concat.lastResult}"/>
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: You just want to see if it errors I guess and get the stack.  I'll try it

Comment: yeah, just in case to continue client side testing, we should all events of HTTPService, so we could determine the place and reason of errors and exceptions. Regards Eugene

Comment: i see you accepted it, would you like to share the solution of your side :) thanks.